# Do home routers have max connection configuration?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I've been experiencing bizarre behavior with my home router, Linksys WRT610N. I have between four and seven devices running on it on average using the DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std firmware.

Specifically, random devices will regularly claim they can not connect to the internet even when on the network and other devices have connected fine to the internet. This appears to happen most when I have applications open which connect to many peers (magnet torrents, bitcoin wallet, ethereum wallet, etc.). Is it possible my router or modem are restricted the number of total connections which can be made?

I've changed many settings in my configuration and can not seem to pin down this behavior. I even switched out the hardware (to a similar model) and firmware from native to DD-WRT.

If there isn't a clear answer, is there a good diagnostic tool I can run to stress my router or modem or to determine what the bottleneck is? Do I just need to add another router to my network?

Comment: Each entry in the router's NAT table consumes memory, as well as eating up CPU cycles to service the table.  A tweak that might extend your router's service, if it's available, is to shorten the amount of time each translation remains tabled.

It might be possible to use SNMP to monitor how many connections your router is processing, (or other parameters, like CPU, memory, and traffic levels) to better isolate where a bottleneck might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DD-WRT, it has a default maximum of 4096 open connections. You can change this setting

You might want to check http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=404846

and https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Router_Slowdown#Increasing_Max_Connection_count_beyond_limits_of_GUI

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

When a program like torrent makes lots of connections, it causes the router to be very busy doing routing and may neglect to do other router duties.

You would want to limit the amount of connections on your torrent program anyway, because too many connections will slow down your torrent.

You should be able to confirm this by temprarily pause your torrent program and as the connections stop, connectivity restores.

Do note, that the more advanced routers (expsenive ones) are able to do this succesfully though, but I've owned this specific router myself and even with the stock firmware, I had these problems myself. I even came to the point where too many connectiosn could literally stop my own computer from doing other internet tasks. This is definitely a limitation on this specific router, but many routers will have similar limitations. Quantity is really not the way to go and reduces overal quality.